# Overloading : operator in python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I want to overload  : operator in python. Is there any way that's possible.
What I want to do is for example- create a myif
I.e

```
Myif(a,b,c):
    Do something
```

Instead of

```
if X:
   Do something
```

Comment: No. Python can't do that. Write instead `if my_if(a, b, c):` and have your function return a Boolean value.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: @kindall is there any workaround or similar thing possible

Comment: `:` isn't an operator; it's just a character used throughout the Python grammar.

Comment: What is the purpose of the new if? You can call a function in the if: ``if Myif(a,b.c): ...``. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Also note that since `if` is a keyword, you can't replace it with a function. @kindall's suggestion is a nice workaround.